# Is it possible to intuitively explain why conditional probability/expectation depends on sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible to intuitively explain why conditional probability/expectation $(P(A|X)$ or $E[Y|X])$ depends on sigma algebra on which it is conditioned not the value of the random variable ?

Formally, it is due to Radon-Nykodin theorem. But in Breiman it says that the intuition behind this is that the relevant information contained in knowing $X(\omega)$ is the information regarding the location of $\omega$. What is the meaning of it.

Comment: I marvel that the explanations [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/780877/6179) did not allow you to make some progress on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional probability or conditional expectation is the best approximation in the square norm of the given random variable $Y$ or indicator function $I_A$ by a function having level sets in the provided sigma algebra. Or having the same level sets as the given random variable $X$. I.e., if points have the same values for $X$, they also need to have the same values for $Y$.

Of course, the idea of level sets only really applies to a finite sigma algebra or random variables with only finitely many values, for the general case it provides a suitable intuition if everything is approximated by step functions.

So while the function values of the levels do not play a prominent role, the sets of points with the same function value or close function values (if the range space is measured in a Borel algebra) are the important part of the construction.